# Android - gridview showing duplicate value(twice)

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, android-arrayadapter

I have 1 app in that i want to display gridview with textview and imageview....

This gridview must change it's value depending upon the button clicked i.e abc button clicked then gridview should display name and image of that particular only and then if i am clicking on xyz Button then data of that only but right now i am getting data of both [image]

I have done

```
mAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this, listCountry, listFlag);

        // Set custom adapter to gridview
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_t);
        gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

public void get_record()
{
    try {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("dbname",
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);


        cur_BeansLegumesn = db.rawQuery(
                "select name,image from "+ Table_name +"   order by name", null);
        System.out.println("connected this i sdone");

        array_BeansLegumes = new String[cur_BeansLegumesn.getCount()];
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        img_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (cur_BeansLegumesn.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                int contentTitleColumn = cur_BeansLegumesn
                        .getColumnIndex("name");
                int img = cur_BeansLegumesn.getColumnIndex("image");
                str = cur_BeansLegumesn.getString(contentTitleColumn)
                        .toString();
                str1 = cur_BeansLegumesn.getString(img).toString();
                // array_BeansLegumes[i]=str;

                // array_BeansLegumes_imgname[i]=str1;
                list.add(str);
                img_list.add(str1);
                System.out.println(str);
//              System.out.println("this is img " + str1);
                i++;

            } while (cur_BeansLegumesn.moveToNext());

        }

        cur_BeansLegumesn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error " + e + "");
    } finally {

        db.close();

    }
```

this will populate adapter

```
public void prepareList() {


        listCountry.addAll(list);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            //System.out.println("this is prepa... " + listCountry.get(i));

        }

        listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        listimgname = new ArrayList<String>();
        listimgname.removeAll(img_list);
        listimgname.addAll(img_list);
        for (int j = 0; j < img_list.size(); j++) {

            System.out.println("img name " + listimgname.get(j));
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier(listimgname.get(j),
                    "drawable", getPackageName());

            listFlag.add(id);

        }
        mAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this, listCountry, listFlag);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_t);
        gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

and this my adapter class

```
public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter

{
    private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;
    private Activity activity;

    public GridviewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listCountry,
            ArrayList<Integer> listFlag) {
        super();

//      this.listCountry = listCountry;
        this.listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.listCountry=listCountry;
        this.listFlag = listFlag;
        this.activity = activity;
        System.out.println("this is contry name "+this.listCountry);
        System.out.println("this is img  name  "+this.listFlag);
        //System.out.println();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("len " + listCountry.size());
        return listCountry.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listCountry.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imgViewFlag;
        public TextView txtViewTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.test, null);

            view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);

            view.txtViewTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            view.imgViewFlag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_default);
            convertView.setTag(view);
        } else {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try {
            view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
            view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("this is error " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

data is comming from DB, and gree imges indicate that i have clicked xyz btn and it also must display img but that is not displaying

this is my log-cat

```
02-11 01:02:02.549: I/System.out(4787): this is btn clickedSeafood
02-11 01:02:02.629: W/FileUtils(4787): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.example.therapeuticfood/databases/Healing_Foods): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
02-11 01:02:02.649: I/System.out(4787): connected this i sdone
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): Cod
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): Halibut
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): Salmon
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): Sardines
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): Scallops
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): Shrimp
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): Tuna
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): img name cod
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): img name halibut
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): img name salmon
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): img name sardines
02-11 01:02:02.659: I/System.out(4787): img name scallops
02-11 01:02:02.679: I/System.out(4787): img name shrimp
02-11 01:02:02.679: I/System.out(4787): img name tuna
02-11 01:02:02.679: I/System.out(4787): this is contry name [Cod, Halibut, Salmon, Sardines, Scallops, Shrimp, Tuna, Cod, Halibut, Salmon, Sardines, Scallops, Shrimp, Tuna]
02-11 01:02:02.679: I/System.out(4787): this is img  name  [2130837516, 2130837529, 2130837573, 2130837574, 2130837575, 2130837578, 2130837585]
02-11 01:02:02.699: I/System.out(4787): len 14
02-11 01:02:02.699: I/System.out(4787): len 14
02-11 01:02:02.709: I/System.out(4787): len 14
02-11 01:02:02.709: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.719: I/System.out(4787): len 14
02-11 01:02:02.729: I/System.out(4787): len 14
02-11 01:02:02.749: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.769: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.779: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.799: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.809: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.819: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.839: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.839: I/System.out(4787): this is error Invalid index 7, size is 7
02-11 01:02:02.849: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.849: I/System.out(4787): this is error Invalid index 8, size is 7
02-11 01:02:02.869: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.869: I/System.out(4787): this is error Invalid index 9, size is 7
02-11 01:02:02.879: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.879: I/System.out(4787): this is error Invalid index 10, size is 7
02-11 01:02:02.899: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.899: I/System.out(4787): this is error Invalid index 11, size is 7
02-11 01:02:02.909: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.909: I/System.out(4787): this is error Invalid index 12, size is 7
02-11 01:02:02.919: W/Resources(4787): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08000d}
02-11 01:02:02.929: I/System.out(4787): this is error Invalid index 13, size is 7
02-11 01:02:03.009: I/Choreographer(4787): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

thanks in advance

Comment: why this view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
            view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position)); code segment in try catch ?

Comment: where is code for button click?

Comment: bcoz i am getting 2nd table value in same gridview ok? but i want it like all old data replaced by new data(img +txtview) but currently i am getting both table data like it appends data... i ma getting name (text view ) but nt imge.. it stops app and saying 02-11 01:03:55.929: I/System.out(4787): this is error Invalid index 7, size is 7 so application stop... to avoid this i put... but it also give this error so...

Comment: btn_fruits.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Table_name = "Seafood";
    System.out.println("this is btn clicked" + Table_name);
    get_record();
    prepareList();

    // Set custom adapter to gridview

   }
  });

Comment: can you please post your button clicked code?

Comment: i've posted in lst comment

Comment: okkkk have solved the problem by just  listFlag.clear(); and some other settings... thanks all